# ¿Como logearme automáticamente a una web y automatizar una descarga con Python?

Tags: python

Me gustaría saber como puedo crear una aplicación en `python` que, al ejecutar, automáticamente ingrese a una web `php`, loggeandose (username & password) y descargue un archivo. (obviamente se puede descargar estando validado en el sistema). 
El gran problema es que la web del login no envía los datos directamente sin antes validar con `javascript`, por lo cual, no hay una pagina por ejemplo `miweb.net/login.php?user==&pass==`  sino miweb.net/index.php.

---

El código final funcionando como aporte a nuestros amigos visitantes.

```python
import urllib.request import urllib import request

#importación de libreria para utilizar el motor de navegación web 
import mechanize import webbrowser

#Conexion y validación de usuario del sistema 
browser = mechanize.Browser() 
browser.set_handle_robots(False)   
browser.open("https://wwww.miweb.org")

#Referencia con el nombre del formulario de envío hacia el javascript
browser.select_form(name="login_form") 
browser["username"] = "miusuario" browser["password"] = "micontraseña"

#Ejecución del código y envío de la información 
response = browser.submit()

#Mostrar el titulo de la página de acceso restringida, para visualizar si nos encontramos con acceso al sistema 
print(browser.title())

#Ejecución automática de la descarga de archivo 

browser.retrieve('https://wwww.miweb.org/enlace_archivo_que_necesito_descargar_automaticamente','Nombre_nuevo_que_doy_al_archivo.csv_extensión_que_deseo_bajar')[0]

#Mensaje que indica la finalización exitosa de la ejecución 
print ('Proceso realizado satisfactoriamente!!')
```

Comment: Necesariamente debe ser en python? en caso no lo sea, te recomiendo https://www.autoitscript.com/site/ y sigas la documentación, tiene un ejemplo de login a facebook; puedes almacenar diversas acciones. Saludos

Comment: Haber, dejame buscar un documento que tengo por ahí que usa un script python para iniciar una búsqueda en páginas web y descargar imágenes, la idea es la misma, el problema es buscarse una librería que permita a python ingresar a la página web automáticamente sin que le ponga problemas.

Comment: Creo que esta pregunta no cumple con los [estándares de calidad](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). No menciona lo que ha intentado hasta la fecha ni pone código que permita reproducir el error. Parece más bien, que está pidiendo que le ayuden con la tarea.

Comment: Mas allá de los problemas de calidad en la pregunta, puedes echarle un vistazo a [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/)

Comment: muchas gracias por los comentarios que me orientan!! para don Toledano, la pregunta no espera un código elaborado. asi mismo, es obvio que realicé intentos, sin resultados. agradecimientos a fredyfx,salahaddin y selenium. por la buena voluntad y orientación. revisaré cada una de sus recomendaciones.

Comment: @CésarAlejandroBorquezMuñoz puedes publicar tu propia respuesta, es válido. De esta forma la pregunta no se queda abierta

Comment: Si la autenticacion se maneja con javascript vas a tener algunos problemas para automatizarlo, para eso creo que tendrias que usar un software para realizar pruebas funcionales como Selenium y crear una prueba que haga lo que quieras.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la biblioteca Mechanize para hacerlo.  Te da bastantes opciones.  Por ejemplo, puedes elegir entre varias formas en la página y también utilizar cookies.

```
browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.open(URL)
browser.select_form(nr = 0)
browser.form['nombre de usuario'] = USUARIO
browser.form['contraseña'] = CONTRASEÑA
browser.submit()
```